# Is the swagger editor demo out of date?

Tags: rust, swagger

I tried generating a stub in Rust [through the editor demo](https://editor.swagger.io/), because I'd rather not download a huge chunk of software that I am only using once. Later on, I encountered problems with crates being out of date or which were trying to use structs/functions that were out of date.

Is the demo out of date and I'll have to download the actual swagger-generator to get the latest server/client stubs in Rust? Is the actual swagger-generator just as old as the demo version in the browser?

Comment: https://editor.swagger.io is the latest version of Swagger Editor. What do you mean by "out of date"?

Comment: Well the stubs I generate from it have old version of certain crates. eg the 'swagger' crate is at version 0.12 (at version 3+) which causes issues since the code it's depending on from third party crates has changed. It's using structs that don't exist, accessing scopes that have been changed and no longer exist. So the stub that's actually generated is basically broken, cannot compile as the dependencies are relying on old version of crates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swagger Editor demo at https://editor.swagger.io always hosts the latest release of the editor.

Note that code generation via the "Generate Server" and "Generate Client" menus is powered by another project, Swagger Codegen. Swagger Editor uses the latest release of Swagger Codegen by default. If you face any issues with code generation, open an issue in the Swagger Codegen repository:

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues

Answer (score 0):

The Swagger Codegen was indeed up to date but the up to date version doesn't seem to be able to generate the most up to date code for rust so switched to openapigenerator instead:

https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator